# (react-pdf) Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _nbind.externalList[num].dereference is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Me aparece este error a cada rato, a veces no sale hasta que presiono algo en la vista y así...

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _nbind.externalList[num].dereference
>   is not a function

Este es el diseño de mi PDF:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  headerImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 120
  },
  footerImage: {
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    marginVertical: 0,
    marginHorizontal: 0
  },
  topTitle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -250
  },
  subtitle: {
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 15
  },
  infoSection: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 250
  },
  testDetailsSection: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 370
  },
  section: {
    marginLeft: 70,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  subfield: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 15
  },
  valueField: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 15,
    marginLeft: 5
  },
  date: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    fontSize: 10,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 120,
    right: 400
  }
});

const PDFReport = () => (
  <Document>
    <Page size='A4' style={styles.page}>
      <View>
        <Image src={myPDFHeaderImage} style={styles.headerImage} />
      </View>

      <View>
        <Text style={styles.topTitle}>REPORTE DE PRUEBA</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.infoSection}>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>INFORMACIÓN DEL EVALUADO</Text>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Nombre:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'Mi nombre'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Correo: </Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'Mi email'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Teléfono:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'300000000'}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.testDetailsSection}>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>DETALLES DE LA PRUEBA</Text>
        <View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Nombre:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'Nombre de la prueba'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Evaluador:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'Evaluador'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Fecha de aplicación:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{new Date().toDateString()}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Estado de la prueba:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{'Estado'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text style={styles.subfield}>Calificación:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.valueField}>{10}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'flex-end'
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.date}>
          <Text style={[styles.subfield, { fontSize: 10 }]}>
            Expedición del reporte:
          </Text>
          <Text style={[styles.valueField, { fontSize: 10 }]}>
            {new Date().toDateString()}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Image src={myPDFFooterImage} style={styles.footerImage} />
      </View>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

Así luce:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi botón de descarga:

```
<PDFDownloadLink document={<PDFReport />} fileName='somename.pdf'>
              {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
                loading ? (
                  <CircularProgress />
                ) : (
                  <IconButton aria-label='download'>
                    <GetAppIcon className={classes.icon} />
                  </IconButton>
                )
              }
            </PDFDownloadLink>
```

Este diseño se hizo con ReactPDF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un bug al hacer re-render, encontré está solución en los issues del repositorio en Github (usar React memo):

```
    const DownloadReport = props => {
      const classes = myStyle();

      const PDFReport = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size='A4' style={styles.page}>
        <View>
          <Image src={myPDFHeaderImage} style={styles.headerImage} />
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.topTitle}>REPORTE DE PRUEBA</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.infoSection}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>INFORMACIÓN DEL EVALUADO</Text>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Nombre:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Correo: </Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.email}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Teléfono:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.phone}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.testDetailsSection}>
          <Text style={styles.subtitle}>DETALLES DE LA PRUEBA</Text>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Nombre:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.testName}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Evaluador:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.evaluator}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Fecha de aplicación:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.appDate}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Estado de la prueba:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.testState}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
              <Text style={styles.subfield}>Calificación:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.valueField}>{props.calification}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View
          style={{
            alignItems: 'flex-end'
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.date}>
            <Text style={[styles.subfield, { fontSize: 10 }]}>
              Expedición del reporte:
            </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.valueField, { fontSize: 10 }]}>
              {getCurrentFullDateWithLocale()}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Image src={myPDFFooterImage} style={styles.footerImage} />
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
  return (
    <PDFDownloadLink
      document={<PDFReport />}
      fileName={`${props.name} - ${props.id}`}
    >
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (
        <IconButton aria-label='download'>
          <GetAppIcon className={classes.icon} />
        </IconButton>
      )}
    </PDFDownloadLink>
  );
};

//Aquí la verdadera solució, React memo.
export default memo(DownloadReport);
```